# glitch on chrome mobile with window dimension

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome, browser

I tested this odd behavior on new Pixel 7 Pro(Android 13) using chrome browser(110.0.5481.65).

Test:

I created a simple app that prints out `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to the screen. I also experienced this behavior using this webpage (https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/window-size.html), (Disclaimer: not hosted by me)

**on initial load without any user interaction when i enter the address and visit the site using Mobile Chrome on Android device (Pixel 7pro) the dimensions are 412x1101.**

**[image: window inner dimensions on initial load without any user interaction]**

**on interaction(tap or click refresh) it is 412 x 775**

[image: window inner dimensions son tap or click]

**and upon scroll as expected the address bar hides and the dimensions are 412 x 831.**

[image: window inner dimensions after scroll]

**Issue: Why is the initial height 1101 ? I would expect it to be 775 and on scroll when the address bar hides to be 831**

**UPDATE:**

Upon further testing it seems this only occurs when i type the url directly in to address bar and click go. If i open the url link through QR scan or clicking on a link tag the innerHeight is as expected. Very Strange

Comment: Same problem. Tried to trigger touch events programmatically, but that doesn't work. Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: I've been a week try to solve this. Have you find any solution?

Comment: Just ran into this bug. SO bizarre. ONLY happens exactly as you described, same exact conditions. Pixel only (6a for me, not on any other Android device), Chrome only (not any other browser, mobile or desktop), typing address into url bar only (not by hitting a link or refreshing an existing page.)

Comment: @temporary_user_name Isn't this happening because the height of the window changes depending on whether the URL/Menu bar is visible? So when you interact with the page, the URL/Menu bar disappears, and therefore the height of the viewport changes?

Comment: No, that's not the case. Interacting with the page does not make the Menu bar disappear. Please don't try to trivialize the bug to something that someone with experience could explain within 2 seconds. If that were the case, it obviously would happen when you opened the page by link as well, on a non-pixel device as well, and in iOS. This is far, far more niche. This happens without scrolling, and the menu bar in Chrome Android only disappears when you scroll.

Comment: It could be related to the usage of the keyboard and how chrome integrates it (?), I think it might be worth trying different keyboards, with different layout settings, and see if it has an impact on the measured innerHeight.

Comment: How does the page behave when you open it on landscape?

Comment: The same problem seems to be addressed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76048293/20783174

Comment: try reset chrome to default setting, and let me know result pls